# Configure VS Code to switch to already open tab in another tab group when opening a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a file in VS Code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, the file is opened in the current tab group of the current editor (even if the file is already open in another tab group).

I am sure there is a setting that will switch the behaviour so that if the file I am opening is already open in another tab group, then the editor will switch to the tab of the already open file (in the another tab group).

But what is the setting to configure this behaviour?

Answer (score 14):

Setting is `Workbench > Editor: Reveal If Open`

> // Controls whether an editor is revealed in any of the visible
> groups if opened. If disabled, an editor will prefer to open in the
> currently active editor group. If enabled, an already opened editor
> will be revealed instead of opened again in the currently active
> editor group. Note that there are some cases where this setting is
> ignored, e.g. when forcing an editor to open in a specific group or to
> the side of the currently active group.

`"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the setting that I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I have used this to open file in new tab, but It will not open redundant tabs

```json
  "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
```