# How to force VSCode to open files just once?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode Layout is split in two columns:

- the implementation files, on the *left* ⬅️
- the test files, on the *right* ➡️

When the `npm test` command fails, it shows at what file/line.
If I click on the URI then **VSCode re-opens the file in the last focused column** (in case it wasn't there already).
But ignores the fact that that file is opened in the other column!

##### How do I force VSCode to open a file just once and focus the one that is already opened?

Comment: See if this fixes it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67756038/836330

Comment: Yes that did it! I upvoted you over there, thank you :)

Comment: Great, I'll close it as a duplicate then.