# Visual Studio Code: switch to opened file instead of opening it again in another editor group

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set up Visual Studio Code with a split view, e.g. the classes in the **left** editor group and its unit tests in the **right** editor group.

I select a file tab in the **left** editor group and add a new method to the class.

Now I want to add tests for this new method. So I click on the test file in the **file explorer** side panel.

What I expect to happen: the unit test file which is already opened in the **right** editor group becomes the active tab.

What happens instead: because the focus is on the **left** editor group it opens another copy of the test file in the **left** editor group even though it's already opened in the **right** editor group.

There's quite a few other ways of selecting the files, but they all involve either opening it in the wrong editor group or searching for the file in a big list of files.

Comment: your usage of terminology is confusing. in your title, you say "window", but when you say "split view", it implies multiple [editor groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups) in the same VS Code window. Can you please learn the terminology and then correct your usage of it so that your question is clear and not confusing?

Comment: Looks like you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67756038/836330.  Probably a duplicate if it solves your issue.

Comment: @Mark you are correct.